# A question about astrology and astronomy

Tags: monastery, past-lives, east-asian-buddhism

my question is astronomical observations and results thereof when applied to humans largely differ from astrological influencing. What Buddhists unlike other religious groups  should do to solve the problems?

Comment: How is that different from astrology?

Comment: I don't understand the question: it says, "to solve the problems" -- what problems? And how that connected to astronomical observations?

Comment: @ruben2020 Astronomy is Scientific

Comment: @chrisW Its one's realisation .like Starwars program is terrible, aweful,user 37920.

Answer (score 2):

Buddhism is not really trying to solve problems in the world. Buddhism is more about internal work and purification of mind through meditation and ethics.

Buddhism is not interested in how astrology or astronomy works since it doesn't lead to freedom from suffering.

Better to just be mindful of the thinking process or the doubt when reflecting on these topics or to be mindful of the process of seeing if one is looking up in the sky.

Comment: sure thank you.user 37920

Answer (score 0):

In [DN 2](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than.html) quoted below, the Buddha denounced practices like astrology, palmistry, divination, face reading, omen reading, magic, dream interpretation, predicting the future and so on as wrong livelihood and "animal arts" for monks. I **highlighted** the relevant parts.

> "Whereas some contemplatives & brahmans, living off food given in
> faith, maintain themselves by wrong livelihood, by such "animal" arts
> as: reading marks on the limbs [e.g., palmistry]; reading omens and
> signs; **interpreting celestial events [falling stars, comets]**;
> interpreting dreams; reading features of the body [e.g., phrenology];
> reading marks on cloth gnawed by mice; offering fire oblations,
> oblations from a ladle, oblations of husks, rice powder, rice grains,
> ghee, and oil; offering oblations from the mouth; offering
> blood-sacrifices; making predictions based on the fingertips;
> geomancy; making predictions for state officials; laying demons in a
> cemetery; placing spells on spirits; earth-skills [divining water and
> gems?]; snake-skills, poison-skills, scorpion-skills, rat-skills,
> bird-skills, crow-skills; predicting life spans; giving protective
> charms; **casting horoscopes** — he abstains from wrong livelihood, from
> "animal" arts such as these. .....
>
> "Whereas some contemplatives & brahmans, living off food given in
> faith, maintain themselves by wrong livelihood, by such "animal" arts
> as [forecasting]: **there will be a lunar eclipse; there will be a solar
> eclipse; there will be an occultation of [a conjunction of the moon or
> a planet with] an asterism; the sun and moon will be favorable; the
> sun and moon will be unfavorable; the asterisms will be favorable; the
> asterisms will be unfavorable; there will be a meteor shower; there
> will be a flickering light on the horizon [an aurora?]; there will be
> an earthquake; there will be thunder coming from dry clouds; there
> will be a rising, a setting, a darkening, a brightening of the sun,
> moon, and asterisms; such will be the result of the lunar eclipse ...
> the rising, setting, darkening, brightening of the sun, moon, and
> asterisms** — he abstains from wrong livelihood, from "animal" arts such
> as these.
> [DN 2](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than.html)